# capturing GPS Coords in Android

Tags: android, gps

I have this code (from a tutorial mostly) that displays GPS coords in decimal form. I would like to use the button to save the current location int some data structure or what not.... that part isn't the issue. I'm wondering how to best capture the GPS data from what seems like a flood of updates.

I am wanting to capture the Coordinates in the onClickListener.

should i use the getLasKnown()?

```
package com.example.geolocation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textLat, textLong;
Button locateBTN;

double mLat, mLong;

ArrayList<Double> mLats = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> mLongs = new ArrayList<Double>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat_output);
    textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.long_output);

    locateBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locate_button);

    LocationManager locationManager =
            (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener =
            new myLocationlistener();
    locationManager
            .requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    0, 0, locationListener);

    locateBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //STUB

        }
    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class myLocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if ( location != null ){
            double pLong = location.getLongitude();
            double pLat = location.getLatitude();

            textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
            textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: When do you want to capture the coordinates? On a button press? Or every x minutes? When the user moves? etc

Comment: on button press. i am sure what ever code should go in the onClickListener...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button click you can use the LocationManager objects getLastKnownLocation method - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get GPS Coordinates is to use `Fused Location API` from `Google`

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html

else you have to put on lot of code to get the right coordinates. THis Api is consumes far less battery too compare to just using GPS coords.